# incorporating prior beliefs while building a confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

this is a homework question that was asked. the question is as follows:

---

let $R_1, R_2, \ldots , R_{n} \stackrel{iid}{\sim } \text {Ber}(p)$ 
let $\bar{R_n} =\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nR_i$
let $\mathcal{I} = (0, \bar{R_n})$ be an asymptotic $CI$ for $p$, of level $(1-\alpha)$
then find the value of $\alpha$

---

the given solution(which I will refer to as case 1) is as follows:

### case 1

$P( \mathcal{I} \ni p ) = 
P( 0 \leq p \leq \overline{R}_ n )\stackrel{?}{=} 
P( p \leq \overline{R}_ n ) = 
P( \overline{R}_ n - p \geq 0 ) ---(1)$

=>$ P( \overline{R}_ n - p \geq 0 ) = 
P\left(\sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{R}_ n - p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \geq 0 \right) \stackrel{CLT}{=} P(N(0,1) \geq 0) = 0.5 = 1-\alpha $
$=>\alpha = 0.5$

I don't see how equation (1) is correct, because I think the following is correct

### case2

$P( \mathcal{I} \ni p ) = 
P( 0 \leq p \leq \overline{R}_ n ) = 
P( -\overline{R}_ n \leq p -\overline{R}_ n \leq 0 ) = 
P(0 \leq \overline{R}_ n - p  \leq \overline{R}_ n ) = 
P\left( 0 \leq \sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{R}_ n - p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \leq \sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{R}_ n}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \right) 
\stackrel{CLT}{\approx} 
P\left( 0 \leq N(0,1) \leq \sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{R}_ n}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \right)$

$P\left( 0 \leq N(0,1) \leq \sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{R}_ n}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \right) \leq 
P\left( 0 \leq N(0,1) \leq 2\sqrt{n} \overline{R}_ n \right) = \Phi(2\sqrt{n}{\overline{R}_ n}) - \Phi(0)$

---

let
$n=150$ and $p=0.001$ and $\overline{R_n}=0.001$, then according to case 1,
$P(\mathcal{I} \ni p) \approx 0.5$,
but according to case 2,
$P(\mathcal{I} \ni p) \leq \Phi(2*12.2*0.001)-0.5 = \Phi(0.02449)-0.5 = 0.5098-0.5 = 0.0098 $
now obviously, $P(\mathcal{I} \ni p)$ cannot have two different values. So, either case 1 yields the correct answer or case2 yields the correct answer.

---

the reason due to which I think equation (1) is not correct, is that in equation (1) it is implicitly assumed that $p \geq 0$, but in the classical statistical framework, there is no way to express/incorporate such prior beliefs. right?

Comment: $p$ is a probabiity, so $p\in[0,1]$ by definition. Isn't it? Moreover, are you sure that $\overline{R}_n=\sum_i R_i$? I'd guess $\overline{R}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i R_i\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @Sergio , my problem with assuming $p \geq 0$ is that it results in $P(\mathcal{I}\ni p)$ having two different values that are not approximations of each other(this point is elaborated upon in the second last para of this question).